# ArrayList / ArrayAdapter .add() function overwriting last element instead of adding to end of array

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

I'm working on a school assignment which is to create a Bookmarking app with 2 activites, a ListActivity called BookNote and an activity called ManageActivity.

All typing must be done in ManageActivity and passed back to BookNote for list changes, reading, and writing data.

My problem is when I call the function "addBookmark" in BookNote activity. What I want to happen is for a new list item to be added at the end of the list with the bookmark objects info in it.

What is happening is that whatever item is at the end of the list is simply overwritten instead of a new item being created.

My code is below with comments stating my intentions of each function.

**BookNote activity**

```
public class BookNote extends ListActivity{
    private ArrayAdapter<Bookmark> adapter;
    private final String FILENAME = "bookmarks.txt";
    public String title = "EMPTY", url = "EMPTY", note = "EMPTY";
    public String bookmarkClicked ="";
    public int listViewID = 0;
    public boolean intentListener = false;
    public int intentReturnCounter = 0;
    public boolean addBookmarkClicked = false;
    public ArrayList<Bookmark> bookmarkList;


    /*When activity is called, list is populated by readData(), addBookmarkClicked is reset to false, intentLister is changed to true if returning from ManageActivity,
      if intentListener is true, addBookmarkClicked will be changed to true if AddBookmark is clicked from the BookNote menubar, a bookmark object will be created with information
       passed back from ManageActivity, and if addBookmarkClicked is true, the bookmark object will be added to the end of the list, otherwise it will be inserted in the same
       list element from which was chosen to edit.*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        bookmarkList = readData();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bookmark>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bookmarkList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        addBookmarkClicked = false;
        intentListener = false;



            intentListener = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("listen", false);

            if (intentListener == true) {
                addBookmarkClicked = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("addBookmarkClicked", false);
                title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
                url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
                note = getIntent().getExtras().getString("note");
                listViewID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("listViewID");
                Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark(title, url, note);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Intent return: True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intentListener = false;

                if (addBookmarkClicked == true) {
                    addBookmark(bookmark);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bookmark Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    addBookmarkClicked = false;
                } else {
                    insertBookmark(bookmark, listViewID);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bookmark Edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                //writeData();
        }
    }



    //reads data when app runs and fills arrayadapter and list with items saved to bookmarks.txt
    private ArrayList<Bookmark> readData(){
        ArrayList<Bookmark> bookmarks = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
            if (scanner.hasNext()){
                String titleScan = scanner.nextLine();
                String urlScan = scanner.nextLine();
                String noteScan = scanner.nextLine();
                Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark(titleScan, urlScan, noteScan);
                bookmarks.add(bookmark);
            }else{
                Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark("Example Title", "Example URL", "Example Note");
                bookmarks.add(bookmark);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return bookmarks;
    }

    private void writeData(){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

            for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
                Bookmark bookmark = adapter.getItem(i);
                pw.println(bookmark.getTitle() + "\n" + bookmark.getUrl() + "\n" + bookmark.getNote());
            }
            pw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Write ERR", "Cannot save: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(BookNote.this, "Error saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //If addBookmark menu item is clicked, this will be called to add a bookmark to the end of the ArrayAdapter.
    private void addBookmark(Bookmark bookmark){
        adapter.add(bookmark);
        writeData();
    }


    //Calls ManageActivity and reports information about app.
    public void gotoManageActivity(boolean addBookmarkClicked){
        Intent manageIntent = new Intent(this, ManageActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("bookmark", bookmarkClicked);
        extras.putBoolean("addBookmarkClicked", addBookmarkClicked);
        extras.putInt("listViewID", listViewID);
        manageIntent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(manageIntent);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_add) {
            addBookmarkClicked = true;
            gotoManageActivity(addBookmarkClicked);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**ManageActivity**

```
public class ManageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String title = "EMPTY", url = "EMPTY", note = "EMPTY";
    private boolean listener = true;
    private boolean addBookmarkClicked = false;



/* When activity starts, check for addBookmarkClicked status, create book */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manage_layout);

        addBookmarkClicked = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("addBookmarkClicked", false);

        String bookmarkString = "";
        bookmarkString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("bookmark");
        if(bookmarkString != null && bookmarkString.length() > 0) {
            if (bookmarkString.length() != 0) {
                String[] stringArray = bookmarkString.split("\\n");
                title = stringArray[0];
                url = stringArray[1];
                note = stringArray[2];
                updateTextViews();
            }
        }
        else { updateTextViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent bookNoteIntent = new Intent(this, BookNote.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

        if(title.length() == 0 || title == null){title= "Empty";}
        if(url.length() == 0 || url == null){ url = "Empty";}
        if(note.length() == 0 || url == null) { note = "Empty";}

        extras.putString("title", title);
        extras.putString("url", url);
        extras.putString("note", note);
        extras.putBoolean("listen", listener);
        extras.putBoolean("addBookmarkClicked", addBookmarkClicked);
        bookNoteIntent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(bookNoteIntent);
    }
```

Comment: why in `onBackPressed` you are starting `BookNote` activity??? just pressing the "back" button you will go to that activity

Comment: You've provided nearly 400 lines of code. Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: @pskink just using to to pass back information instead of writing a new function to do so.

Comment: pass back information by starting second activity via `startActivityForResult`,  see the docs on how it works

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to just what is necessary for adding data?

Comment: Also, is there a reason that you are using a flat file instead of a SQLite database? Using a database and Cursors would make this much easier. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db for details.

Comment: Edits made. Like I mentioned this is entirely for school and it's basically a refresher assignment for the new semester. We haven't touched anything like databases yet.

Comment: @sircrisp try adding a [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) after calling 'add'.

Comment: @torque203 I tried, it had no noticeable affect.

Comment: @torque203
[setNotifyOnChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange), looks like default is true.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! I had to deal with this issue myself as well, a couple of weeks ago.

The main thing is that you will need to re-instantiate your `ArrayAdapter`, or `adapter` in your case.

Now you do the first step correctly:

```
bookmarkList = readData();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bookmark>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bookmarkList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But you will do this again when trying to update the list: I believe you added the new bookmark correctly, but you'll need to re-create the ArrayAdapter for the listview.

EDIT:
I believe I found the peril. 
Right here you will need to re-instantiate the ArrayAdapter, as I mentioned earlier.

```
private void addBookmark(Bookmark bookmark){
    adapter.add(bookmark);
    writeData();
}
```

Basically, whenever you update the data to be shown in your list, you need to do this step...

Comment: I tried adding the following to addBookmark() but still get the same results

`adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bookmark>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bookmarkList);`
        `setListAdapter(adapter);`
        `adapter.add(bookmark);`

Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I think you should add the bookmark to the bookmarkList and then execute `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bookmark>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bookmarkList);` and `setListAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Doing that just gives me 2 duplicate items added to the list, and any time I try to add a new item it overwrites the 2 duplicates with 2 new duplicates.

I added `bookmarkList.add(bookmark);` before the rest like you suggested.

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to create a new ArrayAdapter object as you suggest. However, it **is** necessary to add the new element to the ArrayList used by the adapter. Of course, this can be accomplished by simply reading the whole file again.

Comment: I changed `bookmarkList.add(bookmark);` to `bookmarkList = readData();` in addBookmark(), this got rid of the duplicate entries but I'm still having the issue of the last item being overwritten.